# Rails, form_for validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a concept of sharing pictures between several groups.
A user can create different groups and assign to each group some pictures. Groups name identifies a group. Therefore the group names are unique. And this is checked when a user creates a group.
A user can share his pictures with another groups.
For this I have a page, where user has to type in a group name with which he wants to share a picture. If a group exists, everything is ok if not, a text_field should be marked red.

I have following for creating a new group:

```
<%= form_for Group.new, :url=>{:controller => "groups",:action=> "create_group"},   :validate => true do |f| %>         
    <br class="clear" />
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.text_field :str, placeholder: "group_name" %>
        </div>  
<%end%>

and in group.rb:
  validates :str,      :presence   => true,
                       :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}
```

But what will be the cleverest way to write a form where I check if what is in `<%= f.text_field :str, placeholder: "group_name" %>` exists already? If it exists then everything is ok. It is possible to write different validates - statements?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly

```
Group.new
```

creates a new object on every request

You probably should do in controller

```
def new
  @group = Group.new
end

def create
  @group = Group.new
  if @group.update(resource_params)
    // some success actions
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

In form:

```
<%= form_for @group, :url=>{:controller => "groups",:action=> "create_group"},   :validate => true do |f| %>
```

Comment: I do not want to create a new group because I am not creating it. I just want to check if the group name, that a user typed in, exists in the database. and I want to do it client-side, as a form_for Group.new does

Comment: Then just create a controller action, that makes Group.find_by(group_name: params[:group_name]).
Make request via ajax to it and color form field, when group is already exists.
Sorry for unrelevant answer, your original question is not clear.